# ARM MRS instruction has inconsistency

Tags: arm

Here is the instruction:[image]

Here is an example of one register:[image]

It's all good except op0(o0) is only one bit and all the different registers have two-bit op0s. Should I just drop the upper bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that, according to the [ARM documentation](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0602/latest), the  `o0` field is a one bit field that determines what a complete, two bits value for `op0` would be.

That is, a value of `0` in `o0` is equivalent to a value of `0b10` for `op0`,
and a value of `1` for `o0` is equivalent to a value of `0b11` for `op0`:

[image]